# Vaadin doesn't compiles Widgetset after adding googlemaps vaadin library

Tags: java, maven, vaadin

Today I tried to add [a googlemaps library](https://github.com/parttio/Google-Maps-for-Vaadin) to my vaadin project.
I added the required dependency to my pom.xml, but however after I added the library, maven doesn't wanted to recompile my widgetset, because of this error:

```
    Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.vaadin.tapio.googlemaps.client.GoogleMapConnector'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/Users/kolbm/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/tapio/googlemaps/2.0.0/googlemaps-2.0.0.jar!/com/vaadin/tapio/googlemaps/client/GoogleMapConnector.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 202: The return type is incompatible with AbstractComponentConnector.getState()
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 203: Cannot cast from AbstractComponentState to GoogleMapState
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/Users/kolbm/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/tapio/googlemaps/2.0.0/googlemaps-2.0.0.jar!/com/vaadin/tapio/googlemaps/client/GoogleMapState.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 9: The import com.vaadin.shared.ui.AbstractComponentContainerState cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 19: AbstractComponentContainerState cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]    Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.vaadin.tapio.googlemaps.client.GoogleMapState'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/Users/kolbm/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/tapio/googlemaps/2.0.0/googlemaps-2.0.0.jar!/com/vaadin/tapio/googlemaps/client/GoogleMapState.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 9: The import com.vaadin.shared.ui.AbstractComponentContainerState cannot be resolved
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 19: AbstractComponentContainerState cannot be resolved to a type
[INFO]    [ERROR] Aborting compile due to errors in some input files
```

Here is my POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>client</name>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <properties>
        <vaadin.version>7.7.3</vaadin.version>
        <vaadin.plugin.version>7.7.3</vaadin.plugin.version>
        <jetty.plugin.version>9.3.9.v20160517</jetty.plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <!--<vaadin.widgetset.mode>local</vaadin.widgetset.mode>-->
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin.tapio</groupId>
            <artifactId>googlemaps</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.47.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <!-- Exclude an unnecessary file generated by the GWT compiler. -->
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF/**</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webappDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets</webappDirectory>
                    <persistentunitcachedir>${basedir}/target/tmp/gwt-unitCache</persistentunitcachedir>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                            <goal>update-theme</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <!-- Comment out compile-theme goal to use on-the-fly theme compilation -->
                            <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <!-- Clean up also any pre-compiled themes -->
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/styles.css</include>
                                <include>**/styles.scss.cache</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- The Jetty plugin allows us to easily test the development build by
                running jetty:run on the command line. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.0.RC2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <webApp>
                        <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    </webApp>
                    <scanTargets>
                        <scanTarget>
                            target/classes
                        </scanTarget>
                    </scanTargets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                        <include>**/test*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Vaadin pre-release repositories -->
            <id>vaadin-prerelease</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>

            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>vaadin-addons</id>
                    <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                    <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
                    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                    <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
                </pluginRepository>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
                    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Hope somebody knows what to do, because I found nothing on the internet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using vaadin 7 but version 2.0.0 of googlemaps addon is targeted to vaadin 8.
Try using version 1.3.4 of googlemaps addon